# custom comparator use on single object

Tags: java, comparator

I have created a custom comparator and I know how to use collections.sort however I Want to know how to use it with just two objects.

So in my person class the comparator code looks like this

```
//Default comparator by score
    @Override
public int compareTo(Person p)
{
   return Double.compare(p.score, score);
}
//Custom comparator by name
static Comparator<Person> nameComparator() 
{
    return (Person o1, Person o2) -> o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());       
}
```

To use the default compartor is fine but how do i use the custom one 
something like this

```
//Default
int result = p.compareTo(p4);

//Not sure how to use this one
int result2 = p.compareTo(nameComparator(p4));
```

p and p4 being person objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Comparator<Person>` is a class which has a method [`compare(Person, Person)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method on it.

So, just invoke this method, passing your two instances as parameters:

```
int result2 = nameComparator().compare(p, p4);
```

Note that you can do your "default" example also with the [natural ordering comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--):

```
int result = Comparator.naturalOrder().compare(p, p4);
```

This is identical to [`p.compare(p4)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Comparators.java#52).

Comment: Thank you I realized the other problem i was having was my Comparator wasn't public so i couldn't access it from outside the class

Comment: "so i couldn't access it from outside the class" You would have been able to access it outside the class; just not outside the package.

Comment: Oh right, yes I was trying to access it from the test packages, so I just made it public. Is their any problem with doing that?